# Using SSIS to import data from excel into multiple tables

Tags: ssis

I have one excel sheet which has information which has to be saved in 4 tables. I have to create unique ids for each table.I also have to insert some data into table 1 and then the unique id created there will be used for inserting data into second table(Referential Integrity) . Moreover one table will always get records to be inserted but for rest 3 tables if some data already exists then it has to be updated and not inserted. I m new to SSIS so please guide me on how to proceed further in SSIS.

Comment: That's an incredible broad question. How about you read some tutorials and ask here again when you really have specific problems?

Comment: I know its broad but all that i have figured out yet regarding my problem is that MULTICAST can be a probable solution, still i need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

loads of requirements :)

First, [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205) is an example of a package that loads an excel sheet to a sql database.
You can easily follow it to build your package.

Differences:

You say you need to insert the same data on 4 tables, so between your excel source and your destination, you will add a multicast component and them instead of 1 destination, you will have 4. The "multicast" will create 4 copies of your data, so you can insert into your 4 tables.

The IDs may be a problem, since the 4 destinations will execute separately, you cant get the ID inserted on the first table to update the second. I suggest you do it using a T-SQL on a "Execute SQL task" after everything is imported .

If that is not possible you will need to have 4 separately data flows where on each  one you do the inserts reading from your excel and joining with the result of the previous insert with a lookup task

Comment: Thanx Diego, as you mentioned "Execute SQL task", even I m thinking the same but I m not very clear about it.I have created a Stored procedure to insert or update data into 4 tables. Can you please guide me where exactly will this  stored procedure execute. I mean the sequence of all steps.

Answer (score 0):

Import it into a Temp table on SQL server. Then you will be able to write a query which retrieves from the Temp table to multiple table.

Hope this solves your problem as per your requirement.